# Understanding what is the cause of Error 2345 when using generics

Tags: typescript

Please explain why `bar1` errors and not `bar2` - why are these fundamentally different?

```js
const foo1 = <E extends (a: unknown)=>void>(e:E)=>console.log(e)

const bar1 = <Arg extends unknown>()=>foo1((a:Arg)=>console.log(a))

const foo2 = <Arg extends unknown>(e:(a: Arg)=>void)=>console.log(e)

const bar2 = <Arg extends unknown>()=>foo2((a:Arg)=>console.log(a))
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=68&pln=7&pc=56#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBGGBeGAeAojApgDylzABMIYAKAQwC4YBXMAazBAHcwBKVAPgDcQASxI8KuGlm49QkEABtcAOjkgA5mM4AoTTOgwARlQBOKdBgCCR1XkLEyDZqw6ipCZBWo1LqqbvlKVdSpOLR1wPTcAJjRMbxsiUnJGFnYwUXFPGG8pAWFfcP9lNQ1tXVhDI2izOIIE+2SnNIpXREiPWmzePwUioJCgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lei li's answer is in a general sense the solution - however, a more specific solution is to change a to `never` as it's then "extendable".

```js
const foo1 = <E extends (a: never)=>void>(e:E)=>console.log(e)

const bar1 = <Arg extends unknown>()=>foo1<(a: Arg)=>void>((a)=>console.log(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

`foo1.E.a` should be a superset or equal of `unknown`, but `bar1.Args` is a subset or equal of `unknown`

`foo2.Args` should be a subset or equal of `unknown`, and `bar2.Args` is a subset or equal of `unknown`.

[Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc?noredirect=1&lq=1)